# iPhone app crashes, exc-bad-access second time after release in dealloc

Tags: iphone, crash, exc-bad-access

I am facing a crash "Exc_Bad_Access" I am writing following code. Any of you if answer it could be very helpful thanks. I am trying to play a video in landscape view while rest app remains in portrait orientation. Following works perfectly fine but when I open it second time that is calling openMoviePlayer second time it crashes. I know Exc_Bad_Access sometime is unpredictable or pin point the reason, But trust me it's very small code and it crashes right here everytime while other code is fine I am sure.
**AND YES IF I REMOVE [player release] from dealloc it works fine but I know at that time retain count of player is 1 and that's a memory leak.**

-(void) openMoviePlayer{

```
    VideoViewController *videoScreen = [VideoViewController new];

    UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoScreen];

    navContr.navigationBar.tintColor = kNavbarColor;

    [self presentModalViewController:navContr animated:NO];

    [videoScreen release];

    [navContr release];
```

}

### VideoVIewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

    player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

    player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;

    [player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 480.0, 270.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:player.view];

    [player play];
}

- (void)dealloc {

    [player release];

    [super dealloc];

}
```

Thanks for your help !!!

Comment: Are you sure you haven't released player anywhere else?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
VideoViewController *videoScreen = [VideoViewController new];

    UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoScreen];

    navContr.navigationBar.tintColor = kNavbarColor;

    [self presentModalViewController:navContr animated:NO];

    [navContr release];

 [videoScreen release];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have declared player as a property with retain then you need to write like this instead:

```
MPMoviePlayerController* tmp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                 initWithContentURL:movieURL];
self.player = tmp;
[tmp release];
self.player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;

..
```

and in dealloc:

```
self.player = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application crashed why because you are trying to release the base object created with new is running currently

- new doesn't support custom initializers (like initWithString)
- alloc-init is more explicit than new
- new is not handled in autorelease properly than alloc - init, so you release the object it killed from the memory results in application crash

  ```
  VideoViewController *videoScreen = [[VideoViewController alloc] init];

  UINavigationController *navContr = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:videoScreen];

  navContr.navigationBar.tintColor = kNavbarColor;

  [self presentModalViewController:navContr animated:NO];

  [videoScreen release];

  [navContr release];
  ```

  rest of your code are fine because I used like this code for our application it works fine, all the best.